# Unmatched ) during a Regex grep

Tags: regex, grep

I'm trying to `grep` (recursively) against a number of files/folders, but my Regex during grep is outputting an error.

Syntax:

```
grep -a -r "^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9.]+:+[a-zA-Z0-9\\\!|\[\]~<>{#}?\$%\^\&*\)\(+=._\-]+$" a.txt > b.txt
```

Error message:

```
grep: Unmatched ) or \)
```

I've tried figuring it out by switching around some ")" but to no avail. Any help is appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It is because `\` is escape character, so you need extra `\` to escape `\` itself.

So if you want to escape `(` in regex with `\` you need to write `\\(`.

Comment: Okay, so I replaced '\(' with '\\(' and still receiving the same error.

Answer (score 0):

In basic regular expressions the meta-characters ?, +, {, |, (, and ) lose their special meaning; instead use the backslashed versions \?, \+, \{, \|, \(, and \).

Traditional egrep did not support the { meta-character, and some egrep implementations support ( instead, so portable scripts should avoid  (  in grep -E patterns and should use `[(]` to match a literal (.